# Java JSP getParameter display null word

Tags: java, jsp, servlets, web-applications

I have a "Hello World JSP" i need to get the users name from the URL and display it, It works fine but it needs to display a generic "World" if not user name is there.

Im not sure how to accomplish that? were do i put "world" in my code to make it display if no user name is present?

Thanks!

```
 <HTML>
<BODY>
Hello <b><%= request.getParameter("user") %>World</b>!
</Body>
</HTML>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Because** you want to do this in an *old fashioned way*, do as below:

```
<%

String user = "", wordDisplay = "";

user = request.getParameter("user");

if(user != null && !user.equals(""))    
wordDisplay = user;     
else    
wordDisplay = "World";

%>

<HTML>
<BODY>
Hello <b><%= wordDisplay %></b>!
</Body>
</HTML>
```

Comment: Works just like i wanted, Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

You can avoid the scriptlet by using JSP EL's ternary operator:

```
<HTML>
<BODY>
Hello <b>${not empty requestScope.user ?  requestScope.user: 'World'}</b>!
</Body>
</HTML>
```

Comment: i need to use the get parameter, is a better way to say it

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you to do not use style of coding. But still if you are interested ,then

Try this :-

```
<%
String vuser=request.getParameter("user");
if(vuser==null || vuser.equals("")){
   vuser="World";
}

%>
```

JSP Code :-

```
<HTML>
   <BODY>
       Hello <%=vuser%> 
   </Body>
</HTML>
```

Hope it will help you.

Comment: This is not right, mate ! Either `user` or `World` should display. Not both together.